# How count a space betwen glyph (without glue)

Tags: fonts, formatting, kerning

How do I count width of glyph, and the space between glyphs?

I have:

- font
- word

How to get all information about the space between glyph.

"Test." in font "Times New Roman".
I need get: width "T" space + kerning , width "e" space + kerning , width `\char101` .....

If it is possible, how can I put some box:

string=

> "`\hbox{TeX}` is,"
>   width "TeX" space+ kerning , width "space", space + kerning, width "i" ..... width ","

Box is everything. Box is mathematic code is graphics, everything.

How write this information to a file?

Answer (score 5):

For LaTeX:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\begin{document}

%\tracingoutput=1
\showboxbreadth=5
\showboxdepth=3

\setbox0=\hbox{TeX}
\showbox0

\end{document}
```

You will get this in the log file:

```
> \box0=
\hbox(6.83331+0.0)x18.33334
.\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 T
.\kern-0.83334
.\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 e
.\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 X
```

For more commands for tracing, see *TeXbook*, Chapter 27; or [*TeX by Topic*](http://texdoc.net/pkg/texbytopic), 34.2 Show boxes: `\showbox`, `\tracingoutput`

Comment: This is not answer. How width of glyph "T" if ligatures is in word how width is it? How spacing?

Comment: \documentclass{article}
\newwrite\mywrite
\immediate\openout\mywrite=temp4.txt
\begin{document}
\newbox\mybox
\setbox\mybox=\hbox{a}
\immediate\write\mywrite{\the\wd\mybox}
\setbox\mybox=\hbox{j}
\immediate\write\mywrite{\the\wd\mybox}
\setbox\mybox=\hbox{ja}
\immediate\write\mywrite{\the\wd\mybox}
\setbox\mybox=\hbox{aj}
\immediate\write\mywrite{\the\wd\mybox}
\end{document}    this text show width but not show space between glyph. 'aj' is different 'ja'.

Comment: @Witold: What's your point? `\showbox` or `\tracingoutput` will show the kerning between glyphs, e.g. `\kern-0.83334` in the solution I wrote. If you show the box `\hbox{aj}` you will see `\kern0.55554` in the log file. Please edit your question if you have more requests.

Comment: Is possible to write this kerning into file? and information where is kerning? Please use 'stuff' (with ligatures) no 'TeX'

Comment: `\tracingoutput` not show kerning. @Leo Liu please write this info to separately file

Comment: @Witold: Setting `\tracingoutput=1`, plain TeX would show kernings. The info are wrote to `.log` file. I think you could write a script to extract the info you need fom the log file.